# Connect Cisco 7975 VOIP phone to two separate Asterisk PBX's

Tags: cisco, asterisk, voip

I have a Cisco 7975 registered on an Asterisk SIP server, and I want to register a second line on a second (different IP) Asterisk SIP server.

I tried to do this with firmware version 8.5.3 but it registers only on first SIP server. I used Wireshark on server 2 and I see that when my server sends "SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required", my phone doesn't respond with any message with "Proxy-Authorization" header field (it doesn't send the credentials). What is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have set proxi_adress for second asterix in your XML file?